# Database issues with Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I've got a basic app that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku. I can push it to Heroku with git and it shows the default Rails welcome page, but when I try to access any subpages, (pages that work when I deploy on a local server with `rails server`) I get "something went wrong" messages.

I pulled up the log and I'm get 500 responses from the server and lots of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished` messages which seems to be an issue connecting to the database.

Further, when I tried to run `heroku rake db:migrate`, I get the following errors

```
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adap
ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Per the suggestion above, I did add `gem 'pg'` to the Gemfile After running `gem install pg` and then `bundle install`. Also, I tried `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (on Windows) and get

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter' (>= 0) in a
ny repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter, activerecord
-postgis-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
, activerecord-postgresql-cursors
```

From the suggestion of the book that I'm reading, I ran `heroku db:push` and it competed without error, but it didn't solve the problem of the pages not rendering once the app is push to Heroku.

update: I've tried installing the activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter as suggested as a possible alternative. I updated the Gemfile with

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

and the database.yml file with

```
production:
  adapter: jdbcpostgresql
```

and when I `heroku rake db:migrate`, it still gives me the message telling me to install postgresql adapter

Answer (score 0):

If `heroku rake db:migrate` runs without error, then your database connection info is correct. It's likely that there's another error preventing the page from rendering correctly. If you tail your heroku logs while making a request, are you still getting the same database error? I suspect that you'll find it's a different error that you'll need to fix.

Comment: Your adapter needs to be 'postgresql', not 'jdbcpostgresql'; the latter is for JRuby deploys, which Heroku doesn't run. Try just installing the pg gem as you're doing and using `adapter: postgresql`.